# Laravel multiple file upload validation

Tags: php, laravel, validation, file-upload

I am currently working in a form.

I have some issue with multiple file upload validation. I have only one field in a form which allows multiple file upload.

```
<input type="file" name="file[]" multiple="multiple">
```

And this is my validation,

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'file' =>'required',
    'file.*' => 'required|mimes:pdf,jpeg,png |max:4096',
],
 $messages = [
            'mimes' => 'Only PDF, JPEG, PNG are allowed.'
        ]
);
```

The validation works perfectly but I am not able to display error messages in blade file.

Here are my attempts.

```
@if($errors->has('file'))
    <span class="help-block">
        <strong>{{$errors->first('file')}}</strong>
    </span>
@endif
```

This is for displaying error if no file is uploaded.

Suppose I have uploaded following files,

```
abc.jpg
abc.html
abc.pdf
```

When mimes type validation throws error I am not able to display error message.
Here in this case, error is thrown as `$error->first(file.1)` since validation fails at index 1

This index can be any index according to files uploaded and `$error->first(file.*)`  doesn't work as well.

When I display all error after adding invalid files only from form, I've got these errors.

```
 Only PDF, JPEG, PNG are allowed.
 The type field is required. 
 The number field is required.
 The expiry date field is required.
```

Any one have idea about this. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the good way, but it's fine for my case.

I have validation rules

```
'file' =>'required',
'file.*' => 'required|mimes:pdf,jpeg,png |max:4096',
```

And, Error message

```
'file.*' => 'Only PDF, JPEG, PNG are allowed.'
```

Since I have only one file upload field, I have just checked this error message in a list of all messages and then displayed as follows.

```
<input type="file" name="file[]" multiple="multiple">
@foreach($errors->all() as $error)
    @if($error=="Only PDF, JPEG, PNG are allowed.")
            <span class="help-block"><strong>{{$error}}</strong></span>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Thanks to all guys,

Answer (score 4):

You can use check for the images.

```
$errors->has('file.*')
```

Comment: I've already tried this. This giving error **Undefined offset: 0**

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/array-validation-is-not-working/replies/125729

Answer (score 1):

Try like this to validate

```
'file.*.mimes' => 'Only PDF, JPEG, PNG are allowed.',
```

Comment: validation has no problem. I've problem with error messages

Comment: Once you use this answer, just print whole `$errors` to see the messages, so you will get the idea.

Comment: When I print all errors there is validation error but how to pick that error over there

Comment: Just Check anything your get when using `@if ($errors->has('file.0'))
        <span class="help-block">
            {{ $errors->first('file.0') }}
        </span>
    @endif`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149585/discussion-between-hari-and-sagar-gautam).

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still struggling with multiple file upload issues, here is a working solution for this:

## Validation Rules in Controller

```
    $validated = $request->validate([            
        'files.*' => 'mimes:pdf,jpeg,png|max:4096',
        'files' => 'required',
    ], 
    $messages = [
        "files.required" => "You must upload atleast one file",                      
        "files.*.mimes" => "This file type is not allowed", 
        "files.*.max" => "Max file size is 4Mb",
    ]);
```

## And in blade view, display the errors like so

```html
<form action="{{ url('/multifile') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-       
       data">
        @csrf
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Select files</label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control-file @error('files') 'is-invalid' 
             @enderror" name="files[]" multiple>
             @error('files')
                <span class="invalid-feedback d-block" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </span>                
            @enderror
            @error('files.*')
                <span class="invalid-feedback d-block" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </span>                
            @enderror
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

And if you are looking to show all the errors in blade view, (for all files being uploaded) you could consider using something like this in your blade view:

```html
@if ($errors->any())         
  <div class="invalid-feedback d-block" role="alert">
    <ul>                        
      @foreach (json_decode($errors) as $file_index => $error)
       <li>
         <strong>{{$file_index.': '}} 
           <ul>
              @foreach ($error as $error_item)
                <li>{{$error_item}}</li>
              @endforeach
           </ul>
         </strong>
        </li>
       @endforeach
     </ul>
   </div>
@endif
```

Comment: But why is that the correct way? Could you consider adding details? :)