# Laravel 5.4 : Dynamic validation rule

Tags: laravel, validation, file-upload

I kind of struggle to find the answer to my question, and my test don't prove to be useful. So maybe someone here would have hit the same issue that I'm facing.

I have inputs with the following kind of patterned name `projects-0-1`, `project-0-2`, `project-1-0` and so on... **These are file inputs** so people can upload a document/an image.

So basically, I've been trying to get a validation message that would (ideally) be something like that:

```
$validator->getMessageBag()->add('project-*-*', 'File is empty!');
```

OR

```
$validator->getMessageBag()->add('project-*', 'File is empty!');
```

I tried a couple of things already and nothing seems to work.

The reason I get to add a custom message is that file is simply not validated if it comes empty to the `$request` object. So I first need to check if the `$request->hasFile` and in case it doesn't I want to add the error message.

Things to consider:

- inputs can be dynamically added to the form, so I don't know the exact number of file inputs I need to validate beforehand.
- even if this should not impact the code and validation, it's worth noticing that everything happens through ajax as I embed the form on another website. Therefore I created endpoints etc...

Any hint ?

Comment: Did you try like this `'file.*.mimes' => 'Only PDF, JPEG, PNG are allowed.',` https://stackoverflow.com/a/45188623/5148479

Comment: Yep I tried all that jazz and it doesn't help. I don't have a problem with validation itself, but with matching error messages to file inputs when those are not part of the request as they remain empty when the form is submitted.

Comment: What I basically need is to put a wildcard in the input name in my rules array:

`$globalRules = [
        ...
        'project_documents-0-0' => 'required|file',
        ...
    ];`

I wish the last rules to be able to match any number between 0-9 after the dashes..

So I thought something like that would do:

`'project_documents-*-*' => 'required|file',` but indeed it doesn't..

Answer (score 0):

Right, coming back here in case someone faces that issue too. I found a "hacky" way to get there and it does the trick for me.

As each input file is dynamically added to the DOM, I add an extra hidden input that holds the name of the file input as a value.

Then in my controller I do smth like that:

```
public function createValuesKeyArray ($preset)
{
    $regexPattern = '/^'. $preset .'-[0-9]*$/';
    $customPresets = preg_grep($regexPattern, array_keys(Input::all()));
    $keys = [];
    foreach ($customPresets as $customPreset) {
        array_push($keys, $customPreset);
    }
    return $keys;
}
```

`// This allows me to get all hidden input names in an array in order to get its value from the $request`

`$hiddenInputs = $this->createValuesKeyArray('hidden-project-name');`

Once I get this array, I can do stuff like that and dinamycally add my set of rules for the input files present in the DOM:

```
foreach($hiddenInputs as $hiddenInput){
    $globalRules[$request[$hiddenInput]] = 'required';
}
```

Not sure if this the right way to get there, but it does the job for me and I don't find that code horrible. I'll stick with it until I find a better way.