# Multiple file request validation not working

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5.8

I am trying to upload multiple files with a request validation but the validation rule is not applying correctly. I want only images to be validated. I set also the mime types but it is not working. What seems to be the problem?

I have tried putting 'fieldname.*' and set mimes but it is not working as expected it is blocking even images.

Here is my input field:

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
```

My validation rule:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'content' => 'nullable|string|max:3000',
            'files.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
    ];
}
```

Comment: Which framework is it??

Comment: Im using Laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your rules function as below:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'content' => 'nullable|string|max:3000',
        'files' => 'array|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
    ];
}
```

Also, please make sure that your form have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute as well.

Comment: Hello thank you. I have tried your solution but I get the same results. It is working well with single file. I have browse some answers the approach is the same and they are getting correct results. I don't quite understand yet what happened. I will further investigate. I have referenced my previous solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45188174/laravel-multiple-file-upload-validation

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers. All of your answers are correct. I did restart my server and it solved the issue.